# Finding the distribution function (homework help)

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I do not quite understand what is classified as a distribution function and how to find a density function if one is a distribution function. For example how can I determine if the following is a distribution function? If it is, how do I find its density function? Any advice would be greatly appreciated!
\begin{cases}
e^\frac{-1}{x},  & \text{X > 0} \\
0, & \text{X ≤ 0}  \\
\end{cases}

Comment: What is the definition of a [distribution function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cumulative_distribution_function)?

Comment: Thanks, @Sasha! So, am I correct that I would just take the integral of e^(-1/x) from 0 to infinity to obtain the density function?

Comment: No, that is not correct. Please review your class notes to remind yourself of the relationship between probability density function and the cumulative distribution function. The [wiki page on PDF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_density_function) contains relevant formulae.

Answer (score 0):

To check if this is a distribution function you must chwck the following:
1)  is it increasing?
2) is $\lim_{x \rightarrow -\infty] =0 $?
3   is $\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty}= 1?

(for your example function the answer would be yes).